# Custom django admin forms for bbcode input

Tags: python, django, bbcode

I'm writing a django website, and I want to use the built in admin interface to allow admins to edit some of the content. So they don't have to learn any html, I want them to be able to format the content using simple bbcode tags.

I've written a pair of functions to convert bbcode to and from html markup. Call them html2bbcode and bbcode2html.

Basically, I need the following:

- to pass the html from the database through html2bbcode so that bbcode is diplayed in the admin editing forms.
- to pass the bbcode from the admin form through bbcode2html when the admin presses 'save', before it goes into the database.
- to be able to retrieve the content as html when its actually going to form part of a webpage.

I cannot find out anywhere how to pass the input from the admin interface through a custom function before saving the result in a database (or vice versa). Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

You could have two separate fields in you model - one for html and one for bbcode. Make the html one not show up in the admin interface (by using the exclude property of the ModelAdmin class), so your admins only see and edit the bbcode field. You can get the html content by overriding the model's save method - place your bbcode2html function there. Something along these lines:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.html = bbcode2html(self.bbcode)
    super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Documentation on customizing the admin interface:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/